# Suppose that $0 < a < b$. Show that $\displaystyle 1 + \frac{1+a}{1+b} + \frac{(1+a)(1+2a)}{(1+b)(1+2b)} + \ldots$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $0 < a < b$. Show that
\begin{align*}
1 + \frac{1+a}{1+b} + \frac{(1+a)(1+2a)}{(1+b)(1+2b)} + \ldots
\end{align*}
converges.

**MY ATTEMPT**

This is what I've tried:

\begin{align*}
S(a,b) = 1 + \frac{1+a}{1+b} + \frac{(1+a)(1+2a)}{(1+b)(1+2b)} + \ldots = 1 + \frac{1/b + a/b}{1/b + 1} + \frac{(1/b + a/b)(1/b + 2a/b)}{(1/b + 1)(1/b + 2)} + \ldots
\end{align*}

But I do not know how to proceed from here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the ratio test.

> The ratio of consecutive terms is of the form $\frac{1+na}{1+nb} = \frac{a+1/n}{b+1/n} \to \frac{a}{b} < 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! (+1)